# Devforce classic 3.8.2 with .NET 4.0 framework

Tags: devforce

any idea if devforce classic 3.8 is compatible with .net 4.0 or above? I'm currently upgrading my framework and I would like to know if this is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, DevForce 3.8 is compatible with .NET 4.0 and above, and can be used with VS 2010 and 2012, though for new development we recommend DevForce 2012.